# XML validation with XSD loaded as File vs InputStream

Tags: java, xml, xsd-validation

I'm experiencing different behavior in XML validation if the XSD is loaded as a File or resource.

If i load the XSD as File everything is fine and validation works well:

```
SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
Schema schema = sf.newSchema(new ClassPathResource("my/perfect/path/myFile.xsd").getFile());
Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
validator.validate(sourceToValidate);
```

Instead since i decided to include xsd file into jar i load it as resource, but the behavior is different and i get into a **SAXParseException** when i construct the Schema and error is complaining about some issue in resolving a name in xsd file as a type definition.
The xsd file is absolutely correct

```
SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("my/perfect/path/myFile.xsd");
Source schemaSource = new StreamSource(inputStream);
Schema schema = sf.newSchema(schemaSource); // here i get the SAXParseException
Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
validator.validate(sourceToValidate);
```

I really can't understand why load the xsd as ResourceAsStream causes a different behavior

I'm using JAXB for xml validation

Comment: To summarise the answer from @lance-java: Because a Stream has no idea where it came from, and therefore a relative URI within a Stream, taken on its own, is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that your xsd references other xsd's and your validator does not know how to resolve the references.

You may need to provide a [LSResourceResolver](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/ls/LSResourceResolver.html) to the `Validator`

```java
ClassLoader loader = getClass().getClassLoader();
LSResourceResolver resolver = new LSResourceResolver() {
   public LSInput resolveResource(String type, String namespaceURI, String publicId, String systemId, String baseURI) {
      InputStream stream = loader.getResourceAsStream(systemId);
      if (stream == null) throw new RuntimeException("Could not find " + systemId);
      LSInput input = new DOMInputImpl();
      input.setPublicId(publicId);
      input.setSystemId(systemId);
      input.setBaseURI(baseURI);
      input.setByteStream(stream);             
      return input;
   }
};

String path = "my/perfect/path/myFile.xsd";
SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
schemaFactory.setResourceResolver(resolver);
Source schemaSource = new StreamSource(loader.getResourceAsStream(path), path);
Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(schemaSource);
Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
validator.setResourceResolver(resolver);
```

You will also want to set the `systemId` on the `InputSource` by calling the two args constructor of `StreamSource`.

```java
String xsdPath = "my/perfect/path/myFile.xsd";
InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(xsdPath);
Source schemaSource = new StreamSource(inputStream, xsdPath);
```

See [StreamSource(InputStream, String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/javax/xml/transform/stream/StreamSource.html#StreamSource(java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String))

> This constructor allows the systemID to be set in addition to the input stream, which allows relative URIs to be processed.

Comment: thank you @lance-java. i think it's something similar but i'm not able to use a resolver since it must be setted into validator and my code crush before the validator instance when i have: `Schema schema = sf.newSchema(schemaSource);`.

Comment: You can also call [SchemaFactory.setResourceResolver(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/SchemaFactory.html#setResourceResolver-org.w3c.dom.ls.LSResourceResolver-). I've updated my answer